# MySQL - GROUP BY and display only duplicated

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a log table with username and which browser was used. I want select only users that have access by different browsers.
Example:

```
|-----------------------|
| username  | browser   |
|-----------------------|
| user1     | Chrome    |
| user1     | Chrome    |
| user1     | Firefox   |
| user1     | Firefox   |
| user1     | Firefox2  |
| user2     | Safari    |
| user2     | Safari    |
| user2     | Safari    |
| user3     | Safari    |
| user3     | Chrome    |
| user3     | Chrome    |
| user3     | Chrome    |
|-----------------------|
```

Query need return only dates from user1 and user3, because they are using different browsers.
Like:

```
|-----------------------|
| username  | browser   |
|-----------------------|
| user1     | Chrome    |
| user1     | Firefox   |
| user1     | Firefox2  |
| user3     | Safari    |
| user3     | Chrome    |
|-----------------------|
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `group by` with `having`.

```
select distinct username, browser
from logtable
where username in (select username from logtable 
                   group by username
                   having count(distinct browser) > 1)
```